# How I can make a Sqlite Database in PC for use in my app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Sorry for my english, i'm trying to improve it.

Im new in the Android develpment world but i know the basics.

My question is, How I can make a Sqlite Database in my PC for use in my app?

For example: I would like to make a table whit many names, second names, adress, and fill those  field  in my pc for before use that database in my app for find my contacts, for example. I want to make something like this for another purpose.

Where should I start?

Answer (score 2):

> Where should I start?

I am interpreting your question as meaning that you want to:

- Create a SQLite database on your PC
- Package that database with your app and use it as the starting point for a database on the device

There are many clients for SQLite, including [the command-line **`sqlite3`**](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html), [the SQLite Manager add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/), and [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835069/which-sqlite-administration-console-do-you-recommend). You can use these to create the SQLite database on your PC.

Then, [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to package the database with your app.

Comment: Thanks bro, i´ll put an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

For a 2015 answer, the one that I use is called DB Browser for SQLite: http://sqlitebrowser.org/

It allows you to create a SQLite Database similarly to how you would create an excel document with rows and tables.